# google map new search box style

Tags: html, css

How i can create google map search box style?
The new style with Css and Html

```
<input id="address" style="position:absolute; left:10px;"  type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style it like any other element.

```
element.style {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
transform: translateZ(0px);
background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);
}
#map {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background: #000;
margin: 5em 0 0 0;
}
```

Heres an example on my website: http://www.loadingequipment.com/contact/

Comment: Thanks. But I need to with all the icons there is  ,  same thing